# Import Thunderbird folders from one computer to another?

Tags: thunderbird, import

I use Mozilla Thunderbird.

I have had to change computers and need to know if I can import all the mails and folders from my old work computer to my new one?

When I set up Thunderbird on my computer it does not give upload all my old mails and they are all stored in the inbox and not the folders I had set up.

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I import Thunderbird mail folders into another instance of Thunderbird?](http://superuser.com/questions/316684/how-can-i-import-thunderbird-mail-folders-into-another-instance-of-thunderbird)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. If you are using Windows your Thunderbird profile is stored at %APPDATA%\Thunderbird.

Note that the procedure below will ***remove*** your new profile and replace it with your old one and is for Windows (for Linux the locations are different but the steps are the same).

Assuming you are using your new computer and from it you can access the HD of your old computer:

1. Close Thunderbird
2. With Explorer, find the old Thunderbird profile on the old disk (e.g. E:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird), select the 'Profiles' folder and the file profiles.ini and 'Copy' them (or CTRL+C)
3. Again with Explorer, find the new Thunderbird profile on your new machine (i.e. %APPDATA%\Thunderbird) and 'Paste' (or CTRL+V). When asked, choose to replace what is there with the old data.
4. Re-open Thunderbird, you should see all your old info restored.

Comment: It's even possible to copy or move the profile from TBird on Windows to Linux... I was surprised how easily I could move my Firefox profile, as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not been specified which OS the OP is using and I don't know where on Windoof the Thunderbird profile directory is, so I'll answer for most popular Linux distributions.

There is a profile directory under `$HOME/.thunderbird/` and a `profile.ini`. The `profile.ini` tells Thunderbird which of the folders in that directory to use as profile folder when starting Thunderbird. For example I renamed my profile folder to `profilefolder` and my `profile.ini` looks like this:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=profilefolder
```

This gives me a hint when backing up the profile as well. When you want to move it to another machine, run Thunderbird on the other machine at least once, so that it creates this profile directory structure and files in it and then just copy the `profile.ini` and the `profilefolder` to the `$HOME/.thunderbird` directory. The `profile.ini` shall overwrite the existing one and the next time you start Thunderbird it loads the copied profile.